# How to translate the AST generated by ANTLR 4 to its source code

Tags: java, sql, antlr, antlr4

I am writing a simple parser to translate the query to SQL.
I've completed the parser and got the AST, but now I need to translate those grammar to SQL using ANTLR 4.
Does anybody knows how to print or translate the query `"SELECT" as "SELECT", "FROM" to "FROM"`, etc in ANTLR 4?

I have followed the definitive ANTLR 4 reference book. In that we have to create 2 java files.

In the 1st java file I thought to follow these steps but instead of

```
public void enterInit(ArrayInitParser.InitContext ctx)
{
    System.out.print('"');
}
```

I have changed to

```
public void enterSelect(ArrayInitParser.SelectContext ctx) 
{
    System.out.print('SELECT');
}
```

**ShortToUnicodeString.java**

```
public class ShortToUnicodeString extends ArrayInitBaseListener 
{

  /** Translate { to " */

  @Override

  public void enterInit(ArrayInitParser.InitContext ctx) 
  {
      System.out.print('"');
  }

  /** Translate } to " */

  @Override

  public void exitInit(ArrayInitParser.InitContext ctx) 

  {
      System.out.print('"');
  }

  /** Translate integers to 4-digit hexadecimal strings prefixed with \\u */

  @Override

  public void enterValue(ArrayInitParser.ValueContext ctx) 

  {
       // Assumes no nested array initializers
       int value = Integer.valueOf(ctx.INT().getText());
       System.out.printf("\\u%04x", value);
  }
}
```

In the 2nd java file I followed these steps:

**Translate.java**

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

public class Translate 
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{

   // create a CharStream that reads from standard input
   ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
   // create a lexer that feeds off of input CharStream
   ArrayInitLexer lexer = new ArrayInitLexer(input);
   // create a buffer of tokens pulled from the lexer
   CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
   // create a parser that feeds off the tokens buffer
   ArrayInitParser parser = new ArrayInitParser(tokens);
   ParseTree tree = parser.init(); // begin parsing at init rule
   // Create a generic parse tree walker that can trigger callbacks
   ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
   // Walk the tree created during the parse, trigger callbacks
   walker.walk(new ShortToUnicodeString(), tree);
   System.out.println(); // print a \n after translation
}
}
```

**TRIED WITH STRINGTEMPLATE**

I have tried with StringTemplate in antlr 4. I can able to translate the query `select, from, where` but when I translate the query `and` I couldn't. My code looks like:

```
import org.stringtemplate.v4.*;

public class ToSql extends    BaseListener
{

   /** Translate select to select */
   @Override
   public void enterSelect(   Parser.SelectContext ctx)
   {
      ST select = new ST("select");
      System.out.print(select.render()+"\t");
   }

   /** Translate from to from */
   @Override
   public void enterFrom(   Parser.FromContext ctx)
   {
      ST from = new ST("from");
      System.out.print(from.render()+"\t");
   }

   /** Translate where to where */
   @Override
   public void enterWhere(   Parser.WhereContext ctx)
   {
      ST where = new ST("where");
      System.out.print(where.render()+"\t");
   }

   /** Translate boolOp to AND|OR|XOR */
   @Override
   public void enterBoolOp(   Parser.BoolOpContext ctx)
   {
      ST boolOp = new ST("<and>");
      if (boolOp == and)
      {
         boolOp.add("and", "AND");
         System.out.print(boolOp.render()+"\t");
      }
   }
}
```

**PART OF MY GRAMMAR:**

boolOp      :   OR|XOR|AND;

Thank you.

Comment: if i give the input query as "select fun(a),b from t where a = fun1(2);"          I should get "select a,b from t where a=2;" as output.

Comment: can u please let us know what is not working ?

Comment: I have tried with StringTemplate in antlr 4. I can able to translate the query "select, from, where" but I am trying to translate the query "and" but I couldn't. My code looks like: (see the "tried with StringTemplate" heading above).

Comment: my partial grammar --> boolOp : OR|XOR|AND;

Comment: Actually, I am trying to print "AND" if my query exists "AND" operator or if my query exists "OR", then I have to print "OR" operator according to the grammar boolOp : OR|XOR|AND;

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how code generation works in v4, but in my little experience, i think you could accomplish this by doing syntax directed translation by making your rules in your grammar spit out the generated output.

```
  boolOp returns[String output] : OR {$output=$OR.text}
                                 | XOR {$output=$XOR.text}
                                 | AND{$output=$AND.text}
                                 ;
```

Then in your select statement, you could also do same to return string "select" "where" etc.
You could walk the tree and print out the output by passing the object of the walker to sysout.

You just have to work on your formatting(newline,tab etc) to have a good pretty print output.

Comment: This will work only to the extent that the changes OP wants to make are completely local to each rule.  The point of an AST is that one might want to make changes at one point, that depend on some point far away in the code; that far-away place must exist for the local change to inspect it.  That type of change can't be done with a simple-minded syntax directed translation.  I agree, if OP's problem shoehorns into this, and his translation problem is long-term stable, that this might be an easy way.   But if he has or expects changes needing long distance access, this route will fail him.